# Is there an extension that previews markdown instantly?

Tags: vim, emacs, github, markdown, elisp

In vim, there is a plugin called
[vim-instant-markdown](https://github.com/suan/vim-instant-markdown) that
displays markdown output; and it supports `GFM`!
In emacs, I know there is a
[markdown-mode](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/) that can be used
when we write markdown, and we can preview the content use w3m. However I am
wondering how to make it support GFM.

The author's tutorial seems to have
mentioned that it has this function, but I didn't figure out how.

Since I still would like need w3m(not like vim-instant-markdown, which has no matured w3m-mode), I hope `\C-c \C-c p` to show the markdown output in a
split window, is there any nice configuration?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212340/is-there-a-vim-plugin-for-preview-markdown-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some plugins support realtime preview.  I am using the first one.

- https://github.com/yukihr/Warp
- https://github.com/syohex/emacs-moz-markdown-viewer

Comment: Well, I like `emacs-moz-markdown-viewer` better since it seems easier to use. But it renders slowly(due to network issues?) and cannot be refreshed in firefox. Also it has problems when I use emacsclient, multiple markdown articles cannot be rendered well. And I failed to configure Warp:-(

Comment: Now I realized that `Warp` conflicts with my personal w3m settings. I installed github-markup, but it still has no support for GFM, especially syntax highlight ;-(

Comment: Seems that this question is silly since only with plugins can redcarpet parse GFM right.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on OSX [Marked](http://markedapp.com/) is fantastic and worth the cost. It supports a variety of preview formats and can perform syntax highlighting on the fly

I work in emacs and I have tried various markdown preview modes that work within emacs. None of them worked that well so I switched to Marked instead. I have Marked running next to emacs and every time I save in emacs, Marked updates automatically

### Open buffer in Marked

Adding the function below to your .emacs is also useful to open the current markdown buffer in Marked

```
(defun markdown-preview-file ()
  "run Marked on the current file and revert the buffer"
  (interactive)
  (shell-command
   (format "open -a /Applications/Marked.app %s"
       (shell-quote-argument (buffer-file-name))))
)
```

### Keybinding

```
(eval-after-load 'markdown-mode
  '(define-key markdown-mode-map (kbd "C-c r") 'markdown-preview-file))
```

### Split Screen

I generally run emacs maximized with vertically split buffers. However when I want a Marked preview I need emacs to take up half the screen and Marked take up the other half. [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/) makes this process quick and easy. I have a binding for the left half of the screen, the right half, and maximized. Thus to go from maximized emacs to emacs and marked. Divvy is triggered with `command-shift-space`

Say I am working in emacs maximized and I want to preview a markdown buffer

```
cmd-shift-space l // shrink emacs to the left half of the screen using Divvy
C-c r             // launch Marked with the current buffer
cmd-shift-space r // shrink marked to the right half of the screen using Divvy
```

Note this Divvy shortcuts are ones that you need to setup yourself

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU! This does not answer the question which was about an `emacs` mode. It would be better suited as a comment.

Comment: Fair enough. I use emacs and tried to set up a variety of different markdown previews inside emacs. None of them worked very well so now I just have Marked running next to emacs. It automatically updates when I save in emacs so that is good enough

Comment: Ah, now that is closer to an answer :). Why don't you edit the way you use it into your answer to make it clear that it can be used "with" emacs?

Comment: done, also added some useful .emacs configuration for emacs-Marked integration